# Indexing a file contents in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-map-reduce

**I have a text file which contains some names like below:

Tom,

Harry

Robert

Harry

Matt

Tremp

I want to index those names in ElasticSearch using JAVA APIs which should index all the names automatically.

Can anybody suggest any solution as I am new to ElasticSearch

Thanks in advance**

Comment: you wanna index docs using java or want to index file data automatically???

Comment: I want both the ways: 1.To index automatically 2.To index using java api